# Python - ElementTree can't access all children

Tags: python, xml, parsing, exception

I'm writing a little python program to create a folder structure out of a xml file using `ElementTree`. But if I try to call `findAll(<tagname>)` on the root element I always get the error: "'Element' object has no attribute 'findAll'". But if I go deeper in the tree and call the `findAll()` method on my "season" tag it works just fine. What causes this problem?

Here is how I load the xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

videodata = ET.parse(<xml-file>).getroot()
for show in videodata.findAll('show'): #throws the above exception
    #do stuff
for season in videodata.find('show').findAll('season'): #throws the above exception
    #do stuff
for episode in videodata.find('show').find('season').findAll('episode'): #works
    #do stuff
```

And this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tvshows>
    <show name="" cover="">
        <season number="1"></season>
        <season number="2"></season>
        <season number="3"></season>
        <season number="4"></season>
        <season number="5"></season>
        <season number="6">
            <episode number="1"/>
            <episode number="2"/>
            <episode number="3"/>
            <episode number="4"/>
        </season>
        <season number="7"></season>
    </show>
    <show name="" cover="">
        <season number="1"></season>
        <season number="2"></season>
        <season number="3"></season>
        <season number="4"></season>
        <season number="5"></season>
    </show>
</tvshows>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `findAll()`, the method is `findall()` (not the lower-case `a`)